# ASP.NET 4 JSON DataContractJsonSerializer Lower Case

Tags: asp.net, json, webforms, datacontractserializer

I have a class with several properties all defined in sentence case:

```
Public Class Provider
    Public Property ProviderName As String
End Class
```

I need to be able to pass instances of this through AJAX which I will then be using in JavaScript to add to an array, process etc. Currently I am using the DataContractJsonSerializer to serialize to JSON and return through an ASHX handler. It may just be me being picky, but I don't really like having sentence case properties in JavaScript, I would prefer them all to be lower case, to produce the following:

```
alert(myProvider.providername);
```

With the default DataContractJsonSerializer I simply cannot find a way to do this! With JSON.NET it would appear that it is a simple task, but unfortunately I can't introduce another dependency into this project - as much as I would like to.

Does anybody know of any way to override the format of keys that are generated?

The project is using ASP.NET Web Forms 4.0.

Thanks,

Chris.

Comment: It's not just you, there are others with this obscure fetish, too, to be sure.

Comment: Yeah, thought it wouldn't just be me that was weird!

Comment: So besides @GrantThomas pointing out that I have a fetish, does anybody know of something which would allow me to achieve this?

Comment: One example where this is needed is when we are generating JSON for third party controls and they can only read lowercase. Having them lowercase in C# raises a compiler warning, so we need both. I added a solution below.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to customize the DataMember attribute to use a lowercase name. Here's the syntax in C#, I assume in VB should be similar:

```
[DataMember(Name = "title")]
public string Title { get; set; }
```